# Does jQuery append() close html tags?

Tags: jquery, append

The append cmd doesn't close my tags, but why?

What do i have to change?

```
for (var i = 0; i<=4; i++)
     $("#wrapper").append('<li id=img'+i+'></li>');
```

This always creates only `<li id=img1>`, but no `</li>`?!

Answer (score 3):

Your code should be:

```
for (var i = 0; i<=4; i++)
    $("#wrapper").append('<li id="img'+i+'"></li>');
```

I think you forgot the quotes for the *id* attribute

Comment: without the doublequotes it generated them by itself.

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided does seem to add the tags you want.

If I run the exact javascript you provided, viewing generated source using the web developer toolbar in firefox gives me `<li id="img2"></li>` and inspecting the element in firebug shows me `<li id="img2"/>`.

Both of those are closed and proper xhtml. Though if you aren't using xhtml, the closing tag isn't required anyway.