# jQuery .append() solution for automaticly closed tags

Tags: jquery, tags

What is the best way to add something like this by append

```
<div>
 <a href=""></a>
 <div>
  <pre>
  </pre>
 </div>
</div>
```

I was looking for some tips,
[Does jQuery append() close html tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437870/does-jquery-append-close-html-tags)
[jquery append() not writing closing tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12309372/jquery-append-not-writing-closing-tag)
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/append-automatically-closing-html-tags

but for these tags, nothing works ;/

Comment: the problem was in dynamic content, which needed induction of function what was at the begining

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your question. Are you asking for a way to append *all* the content you've listed to another element?

If so, here's one way. jQuery will self-close elements if you write them as `<div/>`. Let's say you want to append all the content in your question at the end of the `body` element.

*EDIT: You can add attributes even to self-closing tags, such as `<a href="#"/>`, so I've updated the code accordingly.*

You could do that like this:

```
$('body').append('<div class="awesome-class"/>');
$('div:last-child').html('<a href="#"/><div><pre/></div>');
```

I don't know if you can manage it in one chained line, so I did it in two. In the first, I append the outermost `div`, and then inserted all the others inside with the `html` method.

Is this what you're after?

*The code with classes as listed in your comment:*

```
$('body').append('<div class="test"/>');
$('div:last-child').html('<a class="test2" href="#"><img src="#"/>link</a><div class="test3"><pre/></div>');
```

Comment: Is it possible to add this with class attribute?

Comment: Yes, you can use add all manner of attributes, even to self-closing tags, so I rewrote the answer. The first `div` has a class, and the `a` is now self-closing. How's that work for you?

Comment: I will try this, and give a feedback.

Comment: What kind of a loop? If you're nesting this in other jQuery code, please edit your question and add the context so I can give you an answer that accounts for how you're trying to use this. Those two lines of code I gave you work for me by themselves.

Comment: `<div class="test"><a class="test2" href="#"><img src="#" />link</a><div class="test3"><pre></pre></div></div>`

Comment: Sure it does. Look at the revised answer. The last code listing produces exactly what you wrote. Try it. You mentioned a loop, though. There's no loop that you're showing me.